# ReactJS: npm package installation priority with private and public registry

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-private-modules

If I have a private npm package where I have maintained the registry scoped to my @org/package in my application .npmrc file and if someone else registers the same package name publicly on npm as in the package.json i.e. @org/package as it was available.

What happens once the npm -i is executed. Would private package reference maintained at .npmrc file will take the priority or the one published at the public space?